# Looking for a Soul Alternative to Underline in Color with Custom Depth and Thickness Using Pdflatex

Tags: pdftex, color, soul, underline

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,soul}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\setulcolor{red}
\setul{}{2.5pt}
\textcolor{blue}{\ul{\textbf{some text}}}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

This seems to be a simple, efficient way to underline in color with the flexibility of specifying the depth and thickness of the underlining.

Unfortunately, recall having encountered some undesirable conflicting effect within a document when using the `soul` package in the past; although I do not remember exactly what it was.

QUESTION: Is there a simple, alternative approach to the above code that does not make use of the `soul` package, whereby I can underline in color, as well as specify the depth and thickness of the underlining, and able to be compiled with `pdflatex`?

Comment: No. Either live with the soul restrictions or switch to lualatex and use lua-ul.

Comment: your question isn;'t so clear, for basic underlining you don't need a package at all you can use `\underline` the tricky parts of soul, ulem, lua-ul etc are allowing linebreaking, but it's not clear if you need that.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you for your comment; but could you specify what those soul restrictions might be; i.e., the problems that one should expect to encounter when using that package? Many thanks.

Comment: well read the documentation. Most importantly section "2.2 . . . others don’t".  Or search the site here for questions about soul.

Comment: @David Carlisle One can use `\underline`, while at the same time change the color of that line, adjust the thickness, and alter its depth?? It is for these three reasons that I used `soul` in the MWE but requested an alternative approach because of complications with the package.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch yes or simpler just use `\rule` it really isn't complicated to put a rule under an unbroken text `\fbox` has `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` which does exactly what you want except on all 4 sides so doing the same but just on one side really has no issues at all, but you can not have `\fbox` mid-paragraph in text that breaks over th eline....