# Underline command of soul doesn't work with Hebrew

Tags: xetex, hebrew, soul

I am trying to use `soul` to underline a word in a Hebrew document:

```latex
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\setul{0.2ex}{0.1ex}
\setulcolor{red}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\opensansH{Open Sans Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{הקדמה}
קו \ul{תחתון}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get "Missing character" errors:

```
Missing character: There is no ת ("5EA) in font ectt1000!
Missing character: There is no ח ("5D7) in font ectt1000!
...
```

for each letter inside the `ul` command.

Why is that?

I might abandon it and do italics rather than underlining if it is not possible, but I would like to make sure it is not possible.

Comment: See [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298020/polish-letter-disappears-when-striked-out-with-soul-package/298025#298025): soul uses ectt font when analysing and the font does not have the glyphs.

Comment: Alternative: [use \rule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624694/looking-for-a-soul-alternative-to-underline-in-color-with-custom-depth-and-thick) command,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your definition of "not possible":

Swap to lualatex and use `lua-ul` package.

[image: lua-ul]

MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
%\setul{0.2ex}{0.1ex}
%\setulcolor{red}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{red!12}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\opensansH{Noto Sans Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{הקדמה}
קו \ul{תחתון}.

קו \highLight{תחתון}.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'll have to read the doc to see how to get a red underline.

---

Attempt:

Using `\newunderlinetype`, but I do not know enough about bezier curves at the moment.

[image: red underline]

MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
%\setul{0.2ex}{0.1ex}
%\setulcolor{red}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{red!12}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\opensansH{Noto Sans Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]

\newunderlinetype\myunderlinered{\cleaders\hbox{%
    \setlength\unitlength{.2ex}%
    \begin{picture}(5,0)(0,1)
      \thicklines
      \color{red}%
      \qbezier(0,0)(0,0)(5,0)%(0,0)(0.5,0)(1,0)
    \end{picture}%
}}

\newcommand\underLineR[1]{{\myunderlinered{#1}}}




\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{הקדמה}
קו \ul{תחתון}.

קו \highLight{תחתון}.

קו \underLineR{תחתון}.

\selectlanguage{english}
xxx\underLineR{abc}xxx yyy\underLineR{fghp}yyy zzz\underLineR{xyzqj}zzz

\underLineR{b} \underLineR{bb} \underLineR{bbb} \underLineR{bbbb}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addition based on the comments*

Illustrating `\rule` method:

[image: rule underline]

MWE

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor}
\usepackage[soul]{lua-ul}
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{red!12}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\englishfontsf{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Script=Latin,Language=English]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf{Arial}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontfamily\opensansH{Noto Sans Hebrew}[Script=Hebrew]
\newfontface\fsym{Noto Sans Symbols}
%
\newunderlinetype\myunderlinered{\cleaders\hbox{%
    \setlength\unitlength{.2ex}%
    \begin{picture}(5,0)(0,1)
      \thicklines
      \color{red}%
      \qbezier(0,0)(0,0)(5,0)%(0,0)(0.5,0)(1,0)
    \end{picture}%
}}
\newcommand\underLineR[1]{{\myunderlinered{#1}}}
%
\newunderlinetype\myunderlineredb{\color{red}\leaders \vrule height -.65ex depth .75ex}
\newcommand\underLineRb[1]{{\myunderlineredb{#1}}}
%
%\newcommand\underLineRc[1]{\underLine[color=red]{#1}}
\newcommand\underLineRc[1]{{\myunderlineredb{#1}}}


% ⚙ = 9881
%adapted from unisugar package:
%make ⚙ an escape character
\catcode`⚙=11%catcode for letter (unisugar package assigns a unicode char here)
\edef\⚙{⚙}
\catcode`⚙=0%escape character and control sequence

%◇ 9671 begin group
%◈ 9672 end group

\catcode`◇=1% 9671 begin group
\catcode`◈=2% 9672 end group



% underline
% לָשִׂים דָגֵשׁ
%
\newcommand⚙לש{\underLineRc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{הקדמה}
קו \ul{תחתון}.

קו \highLight{תחתון}.

קו \underLineR{תחתון}.
\textenglish{cleaders of picture containing bezier curve}

קו \underLineRb{תחתון}.
\textenglish{leaders of vrule}


קו ⚙לש{תחתון}.

קו ⚙לש◇תחתון◈.
\textenglish{{\fsym \⚙} as escape for \texthebrew{{\fsym \⚙}לש} command}




\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For input, it is easier to define a direction-neutral control sequence escape character (here, `⚙`), begin group (`◇`) and end group (`◈`), and a command `⚙לש` which does

```
\newcommand⚙לש{\underLineRc}
```

and type `קו ⚙לש◇תחתון◈.`, instead of double-directioned material like

```
קו \underLineRb{תחתון}.
```

(Code is OK in TeXWorks; the browser is doing its own interpretation of RTL.)

Comment: For the red underline you can avoid bezier curves with e.g. `\newunderlinetype\myunderlinered{\color{red}\leaders \vrule height -.65ex depth .75ex}`. This also results in better lengths since the length doesn't have to be a multiple of the picture size.

Comment: Alternatively current versions support `\newcommand\underLineR{\underLine[color=red]}`.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks. I've added to answer as visual illustration so people can see. The rule method is much better and practical.